# Is it possible to loop a custom model form in django?

Tags: html, django

Is it possible to create multiple objects for a model in django by looping the same form in a for loop. I am using a custom model form.

My template is:

```html
{% for query in queryset %}
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'academics' %}" style=" padding: 5%">
    {% csrf_token %}                            
    <input type="text" name="Student" class="form-control" id="id_Student" 
    value="{{query}}">
    <input type="text" name="Subject" class="form-control" required id="id_Subject">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Presence" id="id_Presence">
    <button type="Submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="Submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My models.py is:

```py
class Attendance(models.Model):
    Student = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    Hour = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=False)
    Subject = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=False)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Presence = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.Student}'
```

My views.py is:

```py
def academics(request):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        form = forms.AttendanceForm()
        context = {
                    'form': form,
                    'queryset': User.objects.filter(profile__Year='SY',profile__Department='CSE')

                }
        if request.method == "POST" :
            form = forms.AttendanceForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                student = request.POST.get('Student')
                hour = request.POST.get('Hour')
                subject = request.POST.get('Subject')
                boolean = request.POST.get('Presence')
                def bool(boolean):
                    if boolean == 'on':
                        return 'True'
                    else:
                        return 'False'
                form = Attendance(Student=student,Hour=hour,Subject=subject,Presence=bool(boolean))
                form.save()                
        return render(request, 'console/academics.html',context)
```

Currently i can create multiple objects, but with the same values of the last form. ie, the object is created with the values of last form. Here i have looped the form so that n number of forms will be generated for n queries with the name filled automatically in the first field. I know explaining this is little complex. Anyone can help?

Comment: At least your `endfor` is in wrong place. Currently your markup is broken: multiple form begins and only one form end.

Comment: If i place the `endfor` after `</form>` I will be able to submit only one form. Which button is clicked. Only that form will be submitted. How can i submit all at once?

Comment: Use ajax requests.

Comment: I don't know anything about AJAX. Any tutorials or video link?

Comment: checkout formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you mean by "looping a form", but if you want the user to be able to enter a list of arbitrary length of similar sets of data, then what you want is a [Formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/) or a [ModelFormset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets). When it comes back, you validate all the data that he has submitted, and if it's all good then you iterate through it, usually creating or modifying multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

Due to reputation I'm unable to comment but I believe this is how you achieve your desired result. by using **WHILE LOOP**.
I myself have not much knowledge of python & Django but I guess this is the logic. Please correct me if I am wrong instead of down voting.

```py
        var = 0
        n = 5
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = forms.AttendanceForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                while var < n:
                student = request.POST.get('Student')
                hour = request.POST.get('Hour')
                subject = request.POST.get('Subject')
                boolean = request.POST.get('Presence')

                def bool(boolean):
                    if boolean == 'on':
                        return 'True'
                    else:
                        return 'False'
                form = Attendance(Student=student, Hour=hour,Subject=subject,Presence=bool(boolean))
                form.save()
                var += 1
        return render(request, 'console/academics.html', context)
```

Comment: Sry this didn't work! And i think you can't loop the forms as arrays

Comment: I'm looping the view method.

Comment: It throws a name error once the first form is submitted!

Comment: Check now. Hopefully it works. Because that's the extend of my Django knowledge

Comment: Can you please edit the answer with how the template should look like?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong.
You want the form to save multiple entries in one single click?